# Misunderstanding of binary file writing/reading in C

Tags: c

Can someone please explain why the following code segfaults whenever I attempt to do anything with either of the character arrays inside of the struct after I read it in from the binary file? The code is as follows:

```
struct my_struct {
    int filename_len;
    char *filename;
    int size;
    char *contents;
};

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.bin", "wb");
    char *one = "list1";
    char *two = "test file";
    int one_len = strlen(one);
    int two_len = strlen(two);

    fwrite(&one_len, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&one, one_len, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&two_len, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&two, two_len, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);



    struct x *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct x));
    fp = fopen("test.bin", "rb");

    fread(&(temp->filename_len), sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fread(&(temp->filename), sizeof(char), temp->filename_len, fp);
    fread(&(temp->size), sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fread(&(temp->contents), sizeof(char), temp->size, fp);

    // This  does not segfault
    printf("%d\n", temp->filename_len);

    // This does
   printf("%s\n", temp->filename);
   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `temp->filename` point to where ? of course crash

Comment: Please clarify your response, as even when I malloc space for the array of still set faults.

Comment: `fread(&(temp->filename), sizeof(char), temp->filename_len, fp);` this line your fatal error. you must first allocate storage for `temp->filename` and then do `fread(temp->filename, sizeof(char), temp->filename_len, fp);`

Comment: As I just said, even when I allocate space this happens. If I check the return code for the fread line it returns the filename_len

Comment: In addition to the missing allocations, I also don't see where your filename get null-terminated before you print it with %s. You either need to null-terminate it or use something like printf("%.*s\n", temp->filename_len, temp->filename);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fwrite(&one, one_len, 1, fp);
```

`&one` is the address of the *pointer* `one` on the stack, not the location it points to. This means that, instead of writing the string pointed to by `one`, you're writing the bytes that make up its address, potentially along with whatever happens to come after that in memory.

```
fread(&(temp->filename), sizeof(char), temp->filename_len, fp);
```

Similarly, this reads a pointer (or part of a pointer) into `temp->filename`, and may additionally overwrite whatever happens to be after it.

What you need to do is:

```
fwrite(one, one_len, 1, fp);
```

Write the actual contents of the string, not its address.

```
temp->filename = calloc(temp->filename_len + 1, sizeof(char));
fread(temp->filename, sizeof(char), temp->filename_len, fp);
```

Allocate a buffer sized appropriately for the filename, then read data into that buffer.

Comment: +1.  I like your answer better because the use of `calloc` negates the need to explicitly null terminate the string.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to clarify the statements about allocation. This has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

1) You are calling `fread` with the **address of** `temp->filename`.

```
fread(&(temp->filename), sizeof(char), temp->filename_len, fp)
```

You don't want to do this.  `temp->filename` is already a pointer to a char.  Instead pass simply `temp->filename`.

2) You aren't allocating any space for `temp->filename`.  You need to do this after you read `temp->filename_len`.

```
fread(&(temp->filename_len), sizeof(int), 1, fp);
temp->filename = malloc((temp->filename_len + 1) * sizeof(char))
fread(temp->filename, sizeof(char), temp->filename_len, fp);
temp->filename[temp->filename_len] = '\0';
```

Similarly for `temp->contents`